# Difference between runif and sample in R?

Tags: r, random

In terms of probability distribution they use? I know that runif gives fractional numbers and sample gives whole numbers, but what I am interested in is if sample also use the 'uniform probability distribution'?

Comment: Why not look at the code? R is open source.

Comment: Or the documentation... `?runif` and `?sample` both seem pretty clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the following code and output:

```
> set.seed(1)
> round(runif(10,1,100))
 [1] 27 38 58 91 21 90 95 66 63  7
> set.seed(1)
> sample(1:100, 10, replace=TRUE)
 [1] 27 38 58 91 21 90 95 67 63  7
```

This strongly suggests that when asked to do the same thing, the 2 functions give pretty much the same output (though interestingly it is `round` that gives the same output rather than `floor` or `ceiling`).  The main differences are in the defaults and if you don't change those defaults then both would give something called a uniform (though `sample` would be considered a discrete uniform and by default without replacement).

***Edit***

The more correct comparison is:

```
> ceiling(runif(10,0,100))
 [1] 27 38 58 91 21 90 95 67 63  7
```

instead of using `round`.

We can even step that up a notch:

```
> set.seed(1)
> tmp1 <- sample(1:100, 1000, replace=TRUE)
> set.seed(1)
> tmp2 <- ceiling(runif(1000,0,100))
> all.equal(tmp1,tmp2)
[1] TRUE
```

Of course if the `probs` argument to `sample` is used (with not all values equal), then it will no longer be uniform.

Answer (score 7):

`sample` *samples* from a fixed set of inputs, and if a length-1 input is passed as the first argument, returns an *integer* output(s).

On the other hand, `runif` returns a sample from a *real*-valued range.

```
 > sample(c(1,2,3), 1)
 [1] 2
 > runif(1, 1, 3)
 [1] 1.448551
```

Answer (score 0):

`sample()` runs faster than `ceiling(runif())`
This is useful to know if doing many simulations or bootstrapping.

Crude time trial script that time tests 4 equivalent scripts:

```
n<- 100                     # sample size
m<- 10000                   # simulations
system.time(sample(n, size=n*m, replace =T))  # faster than ceiling/runif 
system.time(ceiling(runif(n*m, 0, n)))
system.time(ceiling(n * runif(n*m)))
system.time(floor(runif(n*m, 1, n+1)))
```

The proportional time advantage increases with n and m but watch you don't fill memory!

BTW Don't use `round()` to convert uniformly distributed continuous to uniformly distributed integer since terminal values get selected only half the time they should.

Comment: I don't know if the comment about relative speed used to be true, but it doesn't seem to be anymore.  `n <- 1e7;  microbenchmark(sample(n, n, TRUE), as.integer(ceiling(runif(n)*n)), times=10)` gives a mean time of 684 ms for sample and 467 ms for runif.  For smaller n (e.g., n=1e6) they are nearly the same.