# R - Fastest way to allocate number into bucket

Tags: r, random

I need to split an interval into `n` equal length buckets and then allocate a uniformly distributed random number into the corresponding bucket. The function should return the index of the bucket the random number is allocated to. Here's what I have so far. I'm looking for something more efficient than this, as the same operation needs to be carried out for each element of a large matrix:

```
bucket.index <- function(n, i=1, l=0, u=1)
{
  set.seed(i)
  num <- runif(1, min=l, max=u)
  bucket.length <- (u-l)/n
  buckets <- seq(l+bucket.length, u, bucket.length)
  return (which(num < buckets)[1])
}

bucket.index(n)
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for `cut`.

Comment: Or `findInterval`, which is even faster than `cut`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your function, the variables `l` and `u` don't actually affect the distribution. Compare:

```
# I've removed the `set.seed`
table(replicate(1e5,bucket.index(2, l=0.5, u=0.6)))
table(replicate(1e5,bucket.index(2)))
```

Your current function is just sampling integers 1, ..., n with equal probability, so just use:

```
sample(n, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. But is `sample` based on the same random number generator as `runif`?

Comment: It is, apparently. Got my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978281/difference-between-runif-and-sample-in-r